# Ngrx state undefined in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use NGRX redux library with Angular 12. The state of the application is undefined.

**Index.ts**

```
export interface ApplicationState {
  product: ProductState | undefined;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
  product: productReducer,
};


export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<ApplicationState>[] = [];
```

**App.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Reducer**

```
export interface ProductState {
  formValidation: FormGroup;
}

export const initialState: ProductState = {
  formValidation: new FormGroup({})
};

export const productReducer: any = (state: ProductState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): ProductState => {
  if (state === undefined) {
    return state;
  }

  const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FORM_VALIDATION':
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Action**

```
export interface ProductFormValidationAction { type: 'FORM_VALIDATION' }

export type KnownAction = ProductFormValidationAction | any;

 export const ActionCreators = {
  formValidation: () => ({ type: 'FORM_VALIDATION' } as ProductFormValidationAction)
};
```

The state of the application is undefined on the reducer call, quite not sure what may be the main issue.

**Dispatch Method**

```
import {ActionCreators, GetUsers} from '../../store/action/product.actions'
constructor(
    private store: Store<ApplicationState>
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 this.store.dispatch(ActionCreators.formValidation());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to default `state` to your `initialState`.

```
export const proudctReducer = (state: ProductState = initialState, ...)
```

Comment: If I use this statement then there won't be any use of  this code if (state === undefined) {
    return state;
  } and the reducer is never getting called on dispatch

Comment: @SanJaisy - `if(state === undefined) { return state }` doesn't make **ANY** sense anyway, why are you using it? According to the rules of redux, a reducer should never return undefined - doing so is considered an error.

Comment: Make sense, but if I add (state: ProductState = initialState, ...) the dispatch method never call the reducer.

Comment: @SanJaisy that sounds to me like you may have been attempting to cancel out one bug with another one. Keep the initial state I posted, but also post your code where you do your dispatch.

Comment: I have added the dispatched method in the code, please have a look

Comment: @SanJaisy - how do you know your reducer doesn't get called? Have you removed the `if(state === undefined)` line?